# phpunit: Comparing object param of with() for Mock object

Tags: object, mocking, phpunit

I am trying to compare an object as a parameter of the "with" to my mock object.
When I compare the `var_dump` of expected and actual they look equivalent.
My hunch is that I am doing something wrong in the `->with` parameter.
Thanks In Advance

My Test code

```
public function testAddEntry()
{
    $expected = new Entry();
    var_dump($expected);
    $dbRef = $this->getMock('EntriesDAO');
    $dbRef->expects($this->once())->method('insert')
        ->with($expected);
    $actual = EntryHelper::addEntry($dbRef, $req);
```

Function Code to Test

```
static function addEntry($iDao, $req)
{
$actual = new Entry();
var_dump($actual);
$actual->newId = $iDao->insert($actual);
```

Output from Console

```
class Entry#212 (4) {
  public $id =>
  NULL
  public $content =>
  string(0) ""
  public $date =>
  string(0) ""
  public $userId =>
  NULL
}
class Entry#209 (4) {
  public $id =>
  NULL
  public $content =>
  string(0) ""
  public $date =>
  string(0) ""
  public $userId =>
  NULL
}

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) EntryHelperTest::testAddEntry
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:insert> when invoked 1 time(s).
Parameter 0 for invocation EntriesDAO::insert(Entry Object (...)) does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that two objects are equal.
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, PHPUnit is using [the identity operator (===)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) to check if the objects are equal. As said in the manual

> ...when using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class

Since you are creating a new instance of Entry in the method addEntry(), the comparation will fail.

Comment: I was thinking that may be the problem too, but then I was able to write a test for a different method.. "update" that worked.  I found the difference and root cause. I was assigning the returned value into the object.   $actual->newId = $iDao->insert($actual);  And this must have been modifying the compared value.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause. I was assigning the returned value into the object. 
In the function I was testing,

```
$actual->newId = $iDao->insert($actual);
```

And this must have been modifying the compared value.
I fixed it by separating the assignment to

```
$newId = $iDao->insert($actual);
```

*Note, modifying the $actual after the call to the mock breaks the test still. So this would not work.

```
$actual->id = $newId;
```